# Notify parallel workers within matlab

Tags: matlab, worker

I'm using the parallel toolbox of matlab. Does anyone knows a way to inform parallel workers to update a global variable?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

The parallel workers are separate MATLAB processes, and do not share `global` state either with each other, or with the MATLAB client process. You ''can'' declare and use `global` data on workers (although you are not permitted to place a `global` declaration directly in the body of an `spmd` block or a `parfor` loop), but this is not ideal since you'll need to take extra steps to ensure that the workers have the correct values.